# Regex, match anything unless just numbers

Tags: regex

I have got the following regex expression so far:

```
used-cars\/((?:\d+[a-z]|[a-z]+\d)[a-z\d]*)
```

This is sort of working, I need it to match basically ANYTHING apart from JUST numbers after `used-cars/`

**Match:**

```
used-cars/page-1
used-cars/1eeee
used-cars/page-1?*&_-
```

**Not Match:**

```
used-cars/2
used-cars/400
```

Can someone give me a hand? Been trying get this working for a while now!

Answer (score 3):

There are few shortcomings of your regex `used-cars\/((?:\d+[a-z]|[a-z]+\d)[a-z\d]*)`.

It's checking for `used-cars/` followed by `multiple digits then one character within a-z` **OR** `multiple characters within a-z then one digit`.

`[a-z\d]*` is searching for either characters or digits which is also optional.

It's inaccurate for your pattern.

Try with following regex.

**Regex:** `^used-cars\/(?!\d+$)\S*$`

**Explanation:**

- `used-cars\/` searches for  literal `used-cars/`
- `(?!\d+$)` is negative lookahead for **only** digits till end. If only digits are present then it won't be a match.
- `\S*` matches zero or more characters other than `whitespace`.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4KbLr2/1/)**

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect1